# Jquery Easy AutoComplete Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am trying to use Easy AutoComplete (http://easyautocomplete.com) to make a search dropdown. Here is my code, it is showing the list based on the data returned from the url, however when I click on an option i get two errors:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined
at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (jquery.easy-autocomplete.min.js?body=1:11)
at HTMLInputElement.dispatch (jquery.js?body=1:4625)
at HTMLInputElement.elemData.handle (jquery.js?body=1:4293)
at Object.trigger (jquery.js?body=1:4534)
at Object.simulate (jquery.js?body=1:4860)
at HTMLDocument.handler (jquery.js?body=1:5116)
```

and

```
GET http://conductor.dev/admin/customers/d/addresses.json 404 (Not Found)
```

I dont want to make any get request on the click of the option, I just want the value of the textfield to be the id. Here is my code:

```
 var options = {
        url: function(phrase) {
          return "/admin/customers.json?query=" + phrase;
      },
      listLocation: "customers",
      getValue: "id",
      template: {
        type: "custom",
        method: function(value, item) {
          return item.customers.last_name +","+ item.customers.first_name
        }
      }
       };
       $('#appointment_customer_id').easyAutocomplete(options);
```